# Ancient-Humanity true purpose in the Human-Forerunner war

Tags: video-games, halo

I just watched the Halo 4 terminals and one of them call my attention, I think the name is "***Charum Hakkor***" where the Lord of Admirals attacks a Forerunner planet because there was a flood infestation, the terminal description is **Humanity true purpose**, or something like that. Later in another terminal video there is the Librarian talking about discovering that actually the humans where attacking and fighting the Flood. **Why did the humans never communicate with the Forerunners regarding the Flood menace?**

Comment: Probably because since they knew there was no hope of defeating it *outright*, they'd rather it weaken their enemy at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suggest you that you need to check the "human-forerunner war" in Halopedia. To be short, the name you mention above is the capital planet of the human empire, which was captured after a 53-year long battle between the warrior-servant led by the Didact and the human forces. The reason why they didn't communicate was clear, in my opinion. Because from the very beginning, when the floods invaded, they expanded for survival and thus resulting in the total conflict between human and forerunner. If they were looking for help, they would have to accept the forerunner as their savior and ally, and eventually lose control with the power, which could lead to their overall destruction.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! While wikia you mention may have the correct information it is best to extract the relevant quotes and put them in your answer with a link to the source. Also, we generally are looking for fact based answers or at least opinion supported by fact. This answer would be improved if you could make clear what is fact and what is opinion.

Comment: Alright..... I'm new here so sorry for that

Comment: We all were at one time. My opinion is to try to help new comers feel welcome and have well-received first posts as that will encourage them to stick around :)

Answer (score 1):

The forerunner saga books explained that while the humans were at war with the forerunners we were both also fighting the flood on second fronts. We were losing the war to the forerunners but we're beating the flood, while the forerunners were beating us but losing to the flood. Pretty sure that's why we were given the Mantle which pissed off the Didact because he saw us as being inferior and not worthy of it. So ya not much communicating of any kind going on at that point.

Comment: Can you include a source or quote from the books to improve your answer?

Comment: right after i move and dig my books out of storage I'll find it. Probably about a month out.